# Problema com Datas em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Em minha *model* tenho o seguinte campo:

```
[Column("sdt_DataReferencia")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
[Display(Name = "Data Referência")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DataReferencia { get; set; }
```

Costumo passar ela pelas *actions*:

```
@Url.Action("Create", "Cobranca", new { reference = Model[i].DataRef.Value.ToString("01/MM/yyyy"), IDC = Model[i].Cliente.ClienteId }) "
```

Porém ela tem invertido mês com dia!

**Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com data? utilizar sempre no padrão `yyyy-MM-dd` e só para exibir faço a conversão?**

Comment: A melhor forma, pra mim, é o formato no qual eu não preciso converter hora nenhuma. Tente trabalhar em um padrão no qual você vai ter o menor esforço possível.

Comment: mas não consigo passar pela querystring o padrão brazil dd/mm/yyyy e tenho problemas ao exibir os valores nesse formato, por isso mudei para yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Não seria melhor você setar a cultura no web.config e assim já tratar com datas no formato brasileiro?

Comment: Já setei e ainda sim na querystring ele muda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto se resolve implementando um `DateTimeModelBinder`:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        object result = null;

        string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        string attemptedValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName).AttemptedValue;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(attemptedValue))
        {
            return result;
        }

        try
        {
            result = DateTime.Parse(attemptedValue);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, e);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Registre-o para os tipos `DateTime` e `DateTime?` no `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeModelBinder());
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());

    ...
}
```

Configure também a globalização no seu `Web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
  ...
</system.web>
```